# C#:Search from treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, treeview

I got a treeview data loaded from a XML file. I want to perform a search when the user types something in the textbox. Is that the right way of doing it?? I just want to filter the data. Please show me some example.

The below code is not working.

```
 textBox1.Enter += new EventHandler(txtSearch_TextChanged);

 private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (TreeNode node in this.treeView1.Nodes)
            {

                if (node.Text.ToUpper().Contains(this.textBox1.Text.ToUpper()))
                {

                    treeView1.SelectedNode = node;

                    break;

                }
  }
```

Comment: which part of the code is not working ? Try putting some breakpoints and see how it works with different input

Comment: @Ozgur Dogus: when i typed something in the textbox, no search happening in the treeview

Comment: so the textchanged event not firing ?

Comment: First open the design view and double click on the textbox. this should lead you to the textchanged event that you wrote.Put a breakpoint at the begining of the txtSearch_TextChanged event and check if you code enters the breakpoint in runtime

Comment: @Ozgur Dogus: Changed it and ran the test, the code it did executed but still no search when i typed in the textbox.

Comment: Did you do what i said and if yes please tell if the code entered the breakpoint or not

Comment: @ Ozgur Dogus:Yes, it did enter into the breakpoint.

Comment: Ok. now just enter the name of the first node and put a breakpoint to this line:  if (node.Text.ToUpper().Contains(this.textBox1.Text.ToUpper())) .              check what it returns. it should return true if the searched text and the node are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to register to the text changed event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx

and for finding the specific node use:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Find()
```

mode details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.find

Answer (score 2):

I think another problem could be that the code you provided only looks at the top level of nodes.  You would need to create a method that would recursively go through the node's child nodes until you find a match.  Something like this:

```
private TreeNode FindNode(TreeNode node, string searchText)
{
  TreeNode result = null;

  if (node.Text == searchText)
  {
    result = node;
  }
  else
  {
    foreach(TreeNode child in node.Nodes)
    {
       result = FindNode(child, searchText);
       if (result != null)
       {
         break;
       }
    }  
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
textBox1.Enter += new EventHandler(txtSearch_TextChanged);

 private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (TreeNode node in this.treeView1.Nodes)
            {

                if (node.Text.ToUpper().Contains(this.textBox1.Text.ToUpper()))
                {
                    treeView1.Select(); // First give the focus to the treeview control,
                    //doing this, the control is able to show the selectednode.
                    treeView1.SelectedNode = node;

                    break;

                }
  }
```